# "Cannot GET /" - deploy Node.js project on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I created a simple app to learn a few things about `node.js`. On my `localhost` it works like intended without an error.

When I tried to push the project to heroku I get the following error (by running `heroku logs`):

```
2020-04-12T10:37:36.270547+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" 
host=myproject.herokuapp.com request_id=4d9d211f-cb87-473e-8149-a827b407336d fwd="83.135.100.19" 
dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=404 bytes=360 protocol=https
```

My server looks like this

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./public')));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use('/', routes);

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${process.env.PORT}`);
})
```

The routes file (under `routes/index.js`) looks like this

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const newsController = require('../controllers/newsController');
const quotesCookie = require('./../middleware/quotesCookie');

router.get('/', quotesCookie, newsController.renderHome);
router.get('/category/:category/:page', newsController.renderCategory);
router.get('/search',  newsController.renderSearch);
router.get('/sources', newsController.renderSources);
router.get('/*', newsController.renderError);

module.exports = router;
```

I set the `config vars` in the heroku dashboard to the variables of my `.env`-file, so I have no idea why this is not working. My `public`-folder only includes some static images, so I added that to `git` and don't ignored it. The logs only shows the above error.

I guess it is like always and I'm missing something obvious. Has someone an idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is quotesCookies middleware does? can you try by removing it `router.get('/', newsController.renderHome);` and still issue than you can go in your controller `exports.renderHome` and add some console.log statements. Than use `heroku logs --tail` and see what is log coming.

Comment: Thanks for your response @KamalPanhwar. I removed the middleware and it worked. So I added it back in and strangely it worked too... I have no idea what the actually problem was, but it is working now.

Comment: ok great, I put reply please accept answer, but well basically may be due to re start of app on heroku it start to work, any I have no guess till have look at codes of `controlloer renderHome` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am seeing a middleware quotesCookies in your route. Please try to remove it and use following line

```
router.get('/', newsController.renderHome);`
```

Hopefully it will work. You can do more inspection by checking codes at controller function `newsController.renderHome` and putting few console.log() to see what exactly it is doing, and can use `heroku logs --tail` to see what is incoming.